# Display and plot GPS coordinates (lat/lon) on Webserver in Python

Tags: python, flask, gps, geopandas, folium

For a project I'm working on, I want to create a Webserver to plot and display GPS coordinates of a vehicle. After doing some research, I'm torn between a couple of Python libraries which sound pretty promising, but I'm just not sure which one to use / would be the easiest to use to achieve what I need.

To create the Webserver, Flask seems like the way to go. To plot and display the data, I found these libraries: Folium, Geopandas, Matplotlib... I'm still getting used to Flask so I don't have any snippets of code to share yet, sorry.

My GPS data (longitude and latitude) is continuously being read and stored once per second in .csv files:

```
Latitude,Longitude
99.92225,99.41867
99.92256,99.41879
99.9237,99.41898
99.92168,99.41599
```

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me out or suggest other libraries, here's what I want to achieve:

- How to create a Webserver to:

  - display the continously updating time, lon and lat data
  - track and plot the gps route on a map

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @elhari you can use gRPC service for floating data transfer.

Comment: I think you should check more on direction of leaflets, openlayers (they handle the map and the display, on client side, so they should be in javascript). Then you can link to your API (to get the features of the map) from python

Comment: matplotlib can do it as well... https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_webagg_sgskip.html